# Regex for PHP: match a character within a set of quotes

Tags: php, regex

```
<input name="so and so" id="john doe" value="something something" />
```

**I want to match only the space character that is within the " of a value= attribute.**

I came up with this:

```
value="[^"',:<>/\r\n]*[ ][^"',:<>/\r\n]*"
```

Problem is this matches the whole string, where I just need the space in the matched string from above.

I am reading some tutorials, which leads me to think I need to use a conditional statement, but I can't seem to figure out how that would work. My guess (which of course didn't work) was:

```
(?(?=value="[^"',:<>/\r\n]*[^"',:<>/\r\n]*")[ ])
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry it is for php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bvalue="\K|\G(?!^)[^"]*?\K\s+
```

You can use this to find `spaces` which are in `value="` and before closing `"`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/11

EDIT:

```
(?:(?<=\bvalue=")|\G(?!^))[^"]*?\K\s+(?=[^"=]*")
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/13

Comment: That is close, but not quite working. It will match any string that starts with value=" . In your example, it matched value="dogcat without a closing a " or a space

Comment: Nevermind. It seems to work in the real world. :) Why does it report 4 matches though when there are only 3, and a new match each time you add a new value=" even if there is no closing " or /s?

Comment: @DavidAvellan Also try [like this modification](https://regex101.com/r/cF0xG7/1) of vks neat regex.

Comment: I stand corrected, it is still producing too many matches. @bobblebubble has the best one that worked for me.

Comment: In your own link it is failing. It shows 4 matches when it should be showing 3. It matches whenever it sees: value="

Comment: Look at the top right. It shows green box above your regex. It is actually 5 matches. Where as @bobblebubble produces 3 matches.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1QOYPFC.jpg

Comment: @DavidAvellan use this https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/13

Comment: That one works better and I would put that one in the answer.